# CodeIgniter and Nginx configurations

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, nginx

I developed my CI app and tested it on over 4 Apache server and it's working fine. But aftaer i upload it int to the new server which is Nginx, it has problem with urls. I Googled a lot and approximately did every thing but there was not result. Now here's the problem:

Due to project structure and scale i need every url to be like this:

**http://example.com/myappname/controller/action** 
ex: **http://example.com/myappname/auth/login**

But it's not working. What is working is:
**http://example.com/myappname/index.php?/auth/login**
which is not what i want.

The nginx configuration is:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/nginx/www/mydomain.com/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/$request_uri;
}   
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
location ~ \.php$ {

    # With php5-fpm:
            try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|ttf|woff)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ {
    expires 1w;
}
location ~* \.(css|js|html)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ {
    expires 1w;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your codeIgniter config.php contains the following information:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://domain.tld/";
$config['index_page']   = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

And here is the nginx rewrite rule,

```
server {
    server_name domain.tld;

    root /var/www/codeignitor;
    index index.html index.php;

    # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I have a website in 
http://website.com

and the codeigniter folder in
http://website.com/partners.

I just change the nginx configuration to have a location specifically for this codeigniter folder.

I add it like this.

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

location /partners {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /partners/index.php;
        }
```

As for your case. I think this setting should work like below :

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/nginx/www/mydomain.com/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
} 

#ADD THIS LINE
location /myappname {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /myappname/index.php;
} 

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
location ~ \.php$ {

    # With php5-fpm:
            try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|ttf|woff)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ {
    expires 1w;
}
location ~* \.(css|js|html)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ {
    expires 1w;
}
```

Make sure to test that everything is working by running sudo nginx -t and then restart nginx. Hopefully it will work.